# Acceptance of specific values using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

If I use the annotation `@Size(min = 1, max = 50)` in Hibernate, I can write a string to the database with at least one and at most 50 characters.

But now I need to restrict the possible values to only two numbers: `12342` and `13409`.

Is there any annotation that allows this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Pattern` annotation for example:

```
@Pattern(regexp="12342|13409")
private String string;
```

Otherwise you can write a custom constraint.

See the documentation for further information.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#section-builtin-constraints

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Comment: pls accept the answer, if it's what you are looking for ;)